# Tensorflow custom preprocessing with tf.py_function losing shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

Im writing a model and doing the preprocessing part: I have a method which preprocesses my tensorflow dataset by calling:

`ds = ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)`

I followed the tensorflow documentation and got this code for process_path:

```
def process_path(filename):
  label = get_label(filename)

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
  
  return image, label
```

Then I want to add my own preprocessing, such as rotating the image so I created a rotate method wrapped with py_function as the documentation suggests:

```
def rotate_image(image):
  return tfa.image.rotate(image, random.randrange(-5, 5)/1.0)

def tf_rotate_image(image, label):
  [image,] = tf.py_function(rotate_image, [image], [tf.float32])
  return image, label
```

However when I add this to my process_path the model seems to break and freezes... I added print statements with image.shape after each adjustment and it shows that after the rotate method the image shape becomes `<unknown>` so I believe this to be the error:

```
def process_path(filename):
  label = get_label(filename)

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
  print(image.shape)

  image, label = tf_rotate_image(image, label)
  print(image.shape)
  
  return image, label
```

Output:

```
()
(None, None, 3)
(None, None, 1)
(None, None, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
<unknown>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `tf.py_function`?

Comment: I also tried it 'inline' as image = tfa.image.rotate(...) but that also presented the unknown shape. But to answer your question, I have other methods which need a py_function wrapper such as image manipulation algorithms (denoising) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are losing your shape because of the call to `tf.py_function`.

### Using a function based on tensorflow ops

In that case, because you are using `tfa`, you can simply call the function without wrapping it in a `tf.py_function` as you are using tf ops :

```
def process_path(filename):
  label = 1

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  print(image.shape)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
  print(image.shape)

  image, label = (lambda x,y : (rotate_image(x), y))(image, label)
  print(image.shape)
```

will result in :

```
>>> ds = ds.map(process_path)
()
(None, None, 3)
(None, None, 1)
(None, None, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
(224, 224, 1)
```

### Using a function that does not consist of tensorflow ops

If you want to use a function that does not consist on tensorflow ops, then you can use `tf.py_function`, and set the shape explicitly. This what is done in the guide [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic). Taking the example from that guide :

```
def tf_random_rotate_image(image, label):
  im_shape = image.shape
  [image,] = tf.py_function(random_rotate_image, [image], [tf.float32])
  # the shape is set explicitly because tensorflow can not ensure
  # that the shape is not modified during the execution of the function
  image.set_shape(im_shape)
  return image, label
```

However, when doing that, one assumption that is made by tensorflow is that the shape you are setting is actually correct! The following example will crash, because the function `lambda x:1` does not preserve the shape of the input.

```
def not_shape_preserving(image, label):
    im_shape = image.shape
    # this function does not preserve the shape
    [image,] = tf.py_function(lambda x: 1., [image], [tf.float32])
    image.set_shape(im_shape)
    return image, label
```

Creating the dataset will work, because tensorflow trusts you. However, when trying to use it, you will be met with an error akin to this :

```
Incompatible shapes at component 0: expected [224,224,1] but got [].
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it errors with: ```NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/custom_ops/image/_image_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow14kernel_factory17OpKernelRegistrar12InitInternalEPKNS_9KernelDefEN4absl11string_viewESt10unique_ptrINS0_15OpKernelFactoryESt14default_deleteIS8_EE```

Comment: This related to your installation of tensorflow. I suggest trying to reinstall `tensorflow` or `tensorflow_addons`

Comment: Lets continue that discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226038/tensorflow-custom-preprocessing-with-tf-py-function-losing-shape)

Comment: Why does py_function loses shape information even if it just passes through the tensors?